# How to remove warning message in Chrome when uploading a directory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-upload, webkit

When uploading a directory using `webkitdirectory` in Chrome, there is an ugly warning message that appears.  The message reads: "Upload [number of files] files to this site? This will upload all files from [directory name]. Only do this if you trust the site."

This started just recently in Chrome version 66.0.3359.139.

Is there a way to prevent this warning message from appearing or to at least prevent it appearing over and over for every upload to the same site?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I was here finding how to display this warning . xD

Answer (score 7):

This prompt is a new security feature.

Previously you could socially engineer a user into holding enter and it uploaded their whole home folder to the attacker site. There is no option or mechanism to skip it.

https://crbug.com/637098

Comment: Once again legitimate applications need to put up with a bad user experience just to prevent a far-fetched attack. I could easily think of other ways to mitigate this without causing this disturbing behavior, but it seems the Chromium team too often opts for the simplest solution, disregarding UX considerations.

Comment: The attack isn't far-fetched at all, but absolutely, feel free to share your ideas.

Comment: I dunno, perhaps a "trust site" option so that I don't encounter this dialog 20 times in a 15-minute session with a destination I use constantly?