# Folder selector in javascript without post confirmation alert

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Actually, I want to select folder path and not upload but I am okay with the solution provided on here.

```js
document.getElementById("folder").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var output = document.querySelector("ul");
  var files = event.target.files;

  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
    output.appendChild(item);
  };
}, false);
```

```css
label {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>Folder upload</h1>

<label for="folder">Select folder</label>
<input type="file" id="folder" webkitdirectory multiple/>

<h2>Selected Files</h2>

<ul>
</ul>
```

But I am getting this post conformation message.
[image]
I want to know is there any way (any library anything) to avoid that confirmation box?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove warning message in Chrome when uploading a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225019/how-to-remove-warning-message-in-chrome-when-uploading-a-directory)

Comment: Ya it will but is there any other ways to select the folder path other than this? Just curious! And also I am using firefox for this not chrome and my application is only specific to firefox browser.